# How to handle scenario of same city with multiple names

Tags: algorithm, alias, multiple-instances

Ok, I have a list with some contacts on it filled by respective persons. But persons living in same city might write different names of cities(that I don't have any control on sice the names of cities may change with changing government). 
For example:

```
NAME                CITY

John               Banaglore
Amit               Bengaluru
```

Here both the **Bangalore** and the **Bengaluru** refer to the same city. How can I make sure(my be programatically) that my system does not consider as two different cities but one, while traversing the list.

One solution I could think of is to have a notion of unique ids attached to each city, but that requires recreating the list and also I have to train the my contacts about the unique id notion.
Any thoughts are appreciated.

Please feel free to route this post to any other stackexchange.com site if you think it does not belong here or update the tags.

Comment: How can you get a list of cities with spelling variants ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust ~~Orléans vs Orleans for example. Going to be much more common for languages that don't use the Roman alphabet, but you can write the names in that alphabet.~~ Not awake properly yet. Having read the other answers, I now get what you are asking.

Comment: @gilleain: I have no idea why you give me this example. The remark is about getting a list, which IMO is impractical.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because I misunderstood what you are asking - I thought you were querying why you would get these spelling variants in the first place, not questioning how you could come up with a list of synonyms for city names.

Comment: @gilleain There are million reasons why this arises. In my country, the capital is Bruxelles, Brussels and Brüssel. These three are official names. It is completely unthinkable that one of them takes precedence.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed, hadn't considered the political aspect of city naming. Derry/Londonderry is a particularly tricky one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a table `alias_table` which maps city aliases to a single common name:

```
+------------+-----------+
| city_alias | city_name |
+------------+-----------+
| Banaglore  | Bangalore |
| Bengaluru  | Bangalore |
| Bangalore  | Bangalore |
| Mumbai     | Bombay    |
| Bombay     | Bombay    |
+------------+-----------+
```

When you want do any manipulation of the table in your OP, you can join the `CITY` column to the `city_alias` column above as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM name_table nt INNER JOIN alias_table at
ON nt.CITY = at.city_alias
```

Comment: @me_digvijay Please review this answer when you get a chance, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, instead of aliases, I ended up assigning unique ids to such cities based on their zip codes or any other reliable and fixed factor; basically a one to many scenario like mapping. But the idea is same :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to provide selection from a list of existing Cities and do not allow to enter it by the user manually.

But if you have data already it is more reliable to use alias table proposed by @Tim Biegeleisen

In addition, some automation could be added, as an example, to check is it correct to ignore 2 words difference in a case when it is not first letter by put it on the aliases table with mark as candidate for future review.

Here is examples of reasons for exclusion of first letter:
Kiev = Kyiv
Lviv != Kiev

Comment: How do you get an exhaustive list and keep it up-to-date ?

Comment: But we cannot ignore the cases where there is a difference of just one or two characters other than first letter, but they can represent completely different cities (my be in another country).

Comment: I think that there are a limited number of combinations for possible names of the Cities with mistakes up to two letters  and after some period of time we'll have an exhaustive list. But anyway it is better than use statical table with aliases and analyze new cases manually each time. I also not suggest to ignore directly, but put to the table with aliases as candidate So the reason of the down vote is unclear for me.

Comment: Your suggestions are unrealistic. In 2014 there were 19509 cities, towns and villages just in the US. Collecting an exhaustive list with orthographical variant is an endeavor. Updating the list is practically impossible: only the users entering their address are able to resolve synonyms, and you can bet that they won't.

Comment: The solution can be extended by filtering by countries, regions as well. But in question was mentioned about Cities only, That is why my example only, with Cities, for some cases it could be enough. Anyway, I've recommended to choose from a list as better design in my answer. So I am just suggesting how to solve the problems with existing data. And it is realistic, even with a global case by adding filtering by country/ region.
@Yves Daoust are you  still have any concerns about my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I still don't think it is realistic. How do you get the lists ? Another issue is that if you inhibit entering the city name manually, people will make random choices when the name does not belong to the list. Even a list of countries is problematic.

Comment: Answers to questions: 

1. List of countries. Here is a list of countries - http://www.state.gov/misc/list/. I don't think it could be changed dramatically in daily basis 

2. The initial list can be filled from official sources - as an example postal service of our country provides a structured list sorted by areas - http://services.ukrposhta.com/postindex_new/default.aspx?lang=en.

3. You can allow people to add new Cities to the area, if they cannot found them in a list. It will be easier to merge it in a dictionary than in raw data even if users sometimes will enter one City second time.

Comment: Looks like it is not only realistic, but also very efficient solution even for world wide case.

@Yves Daoust, please let me know if you still have any concerns about suggested solution.

Comment: The problem with countries is that it doesn't change dramatically in daily basis. So that in the long term, it will not be updated as no one will think of it. The effort required to get the lists of cities and keep them updated is disproportionate to the benefit.

Comment: Countries/areas and cities dictionary can be updated only by the needs and biggest efforts can be moved to users,
In my particular case it was not more than 1-2 5-10 min edits per year. Efforts for importing of list of the Cities/ areas - 4 hours once.

Comment: You mentioned that efforts of creating and keep updated of dictionaries of the Cities it more than benefits of this case. The problem is that manually updates of unstructured data in the table with aliases will be much less efficient by the efforts. Because you have to manually insert aliases into table each time data entered, And it is also impossible for international option in a case with Cities with same name in different countries or region.

Comment: In my particular case I've mentioned it was 4-8 hours per week, before customer decided to optimize it with using of structured dictionary.
So it still looks like the best solution for a question, even with for international case.
@Yves Daoust could you please provide some example for solution which can be more efficient than proposed?

Comment: The question was how to handle this scenario. And solution proposed can be valuable in many cases. In my situation, leaving all as is was not an option because of problem with data consistency. @Yves Daoust do you think that anyone will ask questions how to solve the problem, if it is a better option to leave it as it exists? If yes, please post it as your own answer and we will see.